# While using collection view, is there a way to specify the number of cells in each "line"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, screen-orientation

I'm trying to create a collection view with 6 cells.
Each cell will be spaced from each other according to the iPhone orientation (portrait or landscape) and to the iPhone screen size.
Independent of the cell's size it has to be a 2 cells per "line", like a 3x2 matrix while in portrait orientation and a 3 cells per "line", like a 2x3 matrix while in landscape orientation.

My problem starts when defining the constraints, I know it's possible to do this by defining the size of the cells or the spacing, however this doesn't fully covers my problem, I want to know a different way to specify the way my collection view must arrange the cells and the constraints according to his orientation and the size of the screen.

Comment: you better check some collection view from cocoa controls and then do changes to current. Also check appcoda tutorial on collectionviews.

Comment: I searched for an answer for more than 2 hours, are you 100% sure that it's possible to do what I want?

Comment: I think you want to just write a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass.  Check out the [“Advanced Collection Views and Building Custom Layouts” video from WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=219) for details.

Comment: it is possible to specify number of cells in a row